# How to notify a user when subscription is about to expire? Design and architecture advice

Tags: mysql, sql, reactjs

I have a react app running with MySQL DB. In the database there are users(organisations) subscribed to some services.

My goal is to notify these users via e-mail when their subscription is about to expire.

I am thinking to set up a trigger/event scheduler on the DB but what happens after the trigger? How can I make the react app know about the result of the trigger so it can send the e-mails if neccessary? I read that sending the e-mails from the MySQL server should be avoided.

How can this be achieved? Thanks!

Comment: Check out [EmailJS](https://www.emailjs.com/)

Comment: I would consider a separate application that sweeps the membership table looking for something like membership_expire_date < now() + interval 30 days and then send the notification.